# Would Boon of Spell Mastery be overpowered for non-arcane casters?

Tags: dnd-5e, balance, boons

Are there game balance reasons why casting a 1st level spell at will should be restricted to Sorcerer, Warlock, and Wizard?

I used to think the reason might be to prevent unlimited healing or smiting, but Celestial and Hexblade pacts defy that justification.

Comment: Related: "[Can I use the Boon of Spell Mastery as a warlock for a spell that I didn't learn as a warlock, but learned as a different class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/134151)"

Comment: Hmm... I just thought of one possible abuse risk: 96000 goodberries.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Allowing divine casters access to Boon of Spell Mastery should be balanced

In the DMG, p. 287, there's a section called "Changing Spell Lists", which includes the following:

> Modifying a class's spell list **usually has little effect on a character's power** but can change the flavor of a class significantly.

If we take this to mean that there are no inherent balance issues with swapping spell lists around, then by that reasoning, allowing different classes access to this Epic Boon should be balanced, as it would be for a wizard who uses the druid spell list (using a houserule as per the above quote).

In fact, as it stands, the Divine Soul sorcerer can already use this to cast any 1st level spell on the cleric spell list. That said, the Divine Soul sorcerer archetype, as well as the warlock pacts you mention in your question, were all released after the DMG was released.

Comment: +1 for including the relative timing of the sourcebooks.